# Удаление символов в переменной Python

Tags: python, aiogram

Как лучше реализовать удаление символов из сообщения?
Знаю, как можно удалять слова из строки, но символы из конкретного слова — без понятия.
Например, пользователь мне присылает "@user", а мне надо в формат "user".
Пишу бота для тг под aiogram.

Comment: Регулярным выражением, например

Comment: символы из слова можно удалять точно так же, как и слова из строки. Потому что символ это то же слово, а слово это та же строка.

Comment: Можно разбить строку на слова и заменить что-то в словах, а потом собрать обратно. А можно учесть границы слов в регулярке через шаблон `\b`, кажется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = "@user"
x = str.replace("@", "")
print(x)
```